# display alert message for 5 sec

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display an alert message for 5 sec when click the 'update' button and after that to perform the update action.

```
my $cFunction = qq{
\$(document).ready(function(){   
    var w;
    function closeWindow(){ 
    setTimeout("w.close();", 3000);
    }

    function createWindow(){
    //create the popup window.

    w=window.open("","",'width=200,height=100');

    // put something into the popup window
    try{w.document.write('<html><head></head><body><p>Updating...</p></body>    <html>')}catch(err){
    //handle error here
    }
    closeWindow();
    }
 } 
};

print $q->script($cFunction);
<--html form--->

    $cInput_form .= $q->image_button({-src =>  '/media/images/save_1.png',-class => 'upd',-title => 'update', -name =>'Update', -value => $row_id, -onclick => 'createWindow()'});
    print $q->fieldset ({-class => "ui-widget ui-widget-content"}, $cInput_form);
```

but this doesnt work. Why?

Comment: Try like this: `setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 5000);`

Comment: Do you want the alert message to stay for 5 secs and then it hides itselft?

Comment: it still doesn't display the message

Comment: yes after hides to continue the action of redirect to the main page

Comment: you cannot do that as alert() dialog is modal and btw you cannot get reference on it. Use custom message box which will not be modal. I'm talking here about programatically close an alert which your code don't provide any attempt anyway...

Comment: just edited my code but it still doesn't work. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not going to fix your code.

But in case you are not aware : to display/flash notification or warning messages there are various javascript libraries available.

"javascript notification library" search will show many results .

I have used [TOASTR](http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/) and it works great. here is [demo page](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)

Comment: does this prevent the action of updating? because i want to do something like : " updating..." and after 3 sec the message dissapeaar and update is performed

Comment: No it doesn't. but It will flash message for 3sec or 5 second as per configuration in one line.

Comment: how can i display an alert window that stays for some seconds and prevent some action. Do you know a way?

Comment: if my action is server side then i will use Sleep or similar method to wait for 5 seconds on server but not in java script